# cannot type at command prompt in mac single user mode

Tags: mac, command-line, osx-snow-leopard

I am trying to run applejack. At the bong, I press the <kbd>command</kbd> + <kbd>s</kbd> keys. The prompt comes up, but when I type, nothing happens. I have a Mac USB keyboard attached and a dynex USB mouse.

I tried resetting the PRAM & NVRAM according to the suggestions found [here](http://www.justanswer.com/mac-computers/3f2zm-starting-single-user-mode-once-keyboard.html) - essentially pressing the <kbd>Command</kbd>, <kbd>Option</kbd>, <kbd>P</kbd> and <kbd>R</kbd> buttons.

I can log in normally and use the mouse and keyboard. I'm not sure what to do next. Please keep in mind that I am a Mac novice.

---

Note that I have the following setup and intentions:

- Mac OS X Server Version 10.6.8 (Snow Leopard)
- I am trying to run applejack in preparation for updating to maverick.

Comment: Did you reset the SMC?  Unplug the power for a minute, then plug it back in and try again

Comment: @Hefewe1zen oddly, a half hour after posted this, and having the server up and running normally, i tried again and it worked just fine. i had tried several times before posting. so, intermittent is a big issue, but not an immediate problem. if i can understand why it happened, then, perhaps i can deal with it more wisely in the future.

I don't know what SMC is. Another thing I must learn, I guess.

Comment: I'm having the same issue with this, and clearing the NVRAM didn't work either. The terminal just does not accept input while the keyboard works fine both to start single-user mode and to use the computer normally.